# How can i get view with my custom id?

Tags: android, view

In my app i am doing movie theaters. And i have a lot of custom button(seats).
All button have custom id. I know the all id from saloon. I want to get my view when

i get the id.How can i do that? I dont want to get when i click.

```
    View v=findViewById(Mycustomid)
```

is not working. Any suggestion? When i get the view i will change background.Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “is not working”? It doesn't compile? It doesn't find anything? It crashes? Don't just answer these questions, provide also any error message you get.

Comment: It is getting null. view is null

Comment: Post your xml with your "custom ids".

Comment: This means either the XML does not have this specific ID or you are loading a different XML.

Comment: This is my custom id =12104106 for one of my seat.1 means is not clicked,2 means status,04 row id,06 column id. For all seat is unique

Comment: are you sure you assign id as `findViewById(R.id.mycustomid)` not `findViewById(mycustomid)`?

Comment: no i am doing view.setid(my custom id)

Comment: For the love of god post the code where you generate and/or set your ids.

Comment: @Apurva is it possible? When i want to findViewById(R.id.mycustomid) it is not find my customid and it is force to declire id to R file?

Comment: I can do that in my app, but if you do so you'll need to do that again and again until all your ids are not included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get using id's assigned by code use parent view object in which you are adding views dynamically like:

```
View v=View_object_in_which_Mycustomid_added.findViewById(Mycustomid)
```

Comment: My main layout right? i must for loop for all seat right?

Comment: @DuyguK: i hope you are calling `somelayout.addView(view)` right? then use `somelayout.findViewById(Mycustomid)`

Comment: Hi i did like this public static View getmyId(int id){
  return mainseatlayout.findViewById(id);
 } i am getting null. I am holding id string type  and i am converting integer. This is my id 16103118

Comment: i am calling like this View v=SeatActivity.getmyId(leftset);

Comment: @DuyguK: are you sure you are calling getmyId after adding views to layout?